# HTML validation with EJS templates as "text/template" elements

Tags: javascript, html, validation, backbone.js, ejs

What's the latest thinking on HTML validation when using a framework like Backbone or Meteor and constructing views in the client from EJS templates?

The problem seems to be that `name` is not an official attribute for a `<script>` tag.

My code looks like:

```
<div id="templates">
<script name="template_name" type="text/template">
  <p class="summary">
    <img src="<%= this.model.image() %>"/>
    <br/>
    <%= this.model.summary() %>
  </p>
  <div>
    <%= this.model.content() %>
  </div>
</script>
<!-- etc... -->
</div>
```

The validation error is

```
Attribute name not allowed on element script at this point.
<script name='hover_grid' type='text/template'>
Attributes for element script:
Global attributes
src
async
defer
type
charset
```

Do I wait for this to be supported and defend this approach or is there a way to make this markup valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that `name` is actually `id`

```
<script id="template_name" type="text/template">
```

Comment: No problem, usually simple answers are in front of your eyes but the brain is telling you something else :)